# Using django-multiupload within a ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms

There are two models, a main one containing information on companies and a ForeignKey model that links files to the company model. I now want to integrate a MultiFileField on my form that allows for uploading multiple files at once (using [django-multiupload](http://chive.ch/django-multiupload/)).

Unfortunately, whenever I send the form, I get a "This field is required." error for my MultiFileField.

Here is my code:

```
# models.py
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    note = models.TextField()

class CompanyData(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to="attachments")

# forms.py
class CompanyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    attachments = MultiFileField(min_num=1, max_num=3, max_file_size=1024*1024*5)

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__'

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(CompanyForm, self).save(commit)
        for each in self.cleaned_data['attachments']:
            CompanyData.objects.create(document=each, company=instance)
        return instance

# views.py
def company_edit(request, pk):
    current_company = get_object_or_404(Company, pk=pk)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CompanyForm(request.POST, instance=current_company)
        if form.is_valid():
            current_company = form.save(commit=False)
            current_company.save()
            return redirect('company_detail', pk=current_company.pk)
    else:
        form = CompanyForm(instance=current_company)

    contexts = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'company_edit.html', contexts)

# company_edit.html
  <form method="POST" class="post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit" class="save">Save</button>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case fellow django-newbies come across a similar problem: I was just missing request.FILES in

```
form = CompanyForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=current_company)
```